Timing program with clock()
I'm trying to time my program using time.h. Code looks like below and I'm using gcc to compile.
My problem is when I try to run this code (I'm using Visual Studio Code), start and end have approximately the same time, and solutionFound is outrageously large for some reason (several orders of magnitude larger than end, occasionally negative). Obviously these times are not right, but I don't know why or how to fix it.
main.c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    // some input/output using printf() and scanf() to get user options
    int maxLength; scanf("%d", &maxLength);
    
    clock_t     start,              solutionFound, end;
    long double timeToFindSolution, timeToRun;

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 1; i < maxLength; i++;)
    {
        // work...
        if(match()) solutionFound = clock(); // match() defined elsewhere in file
    }

    end = clock();

    timeToFindSolution = ((long double) (solutionFound - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    timeToRun          = ((long double) (end - start))           / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("solution found in %Lf, took %Lf to run\n", timeToFindSolution, timeToRun);
    printf("start = %f, foundPswd = %f, end = %f\n", (double)start, (double)solutionFound, (double)end);

    return 0;
}

I tried putting end = clock() inside my loop but that had no effect. I found a lot of questions on Stack Overflow about how to time a program but didn't see anyone that had a similar problem.
I also tried making timeToFindSolution and timeToRun doubles instead of long doubles (not expecting the program to run very long anyway), still had the same problem.

Was a solution ever found? With that code, how would you ever know? If not, the value of solutionFound is undefined.

This code will fail to compile, you cannot use the function call operator () on a clock_t, generally speaking .

Please provide a minimal working example. The posted code does not even compile.

@user207421 Yes, a solution is always found. I may have cut out too much detail of the code, but the original main.c is 200 lines of code and I didn't want the snippet to be too crowded.

@M.M Really? I've used similar code to time programs in C++ before, and this code did compile, without errors. I also saw several tutorials online that said to use clock() (eg: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-program-in-c/#).

@sunner Your code does not compile without errors: example. You are using the identifier solutionFound as both a function and a variable, but it's not a function -- it's a variable of type clock_t. You are also using the identifier condition which is not declared anywhere.

Alright, I modified my code snippet. It was using a bit of pseudocode which may have been confusing.

This illustrates the importance of a [mre]. If you have no idea how to debug a program, and decide to provide an interpretation of your code instead of the exact code, you are not going to get useful answers. The problem remains here that solutionFound is not initialized to anything. And so if match() never returns non-zero before i exceeds maxLength, then its value will be indeterminate and you have undefined behavior. If you assert that match() always returns non-zero, we cannot tell you if it actually does, because you haven't shown it. Compile with all warnings enabled: -Wall

Initialize solutionFound to 0; print the raw values (maybe convert to intmax_t before printing using PRIDMAX from <inttypes.h> in the format string) so you can see what the arithmetic is working with.  Print what the computer actually got so you can be sure it got what you expected.  It's a basic debugging technique.

Initializing solutionFound to 0 helped, made me realize there was a case I hadn't accounted for where a solution wasn't found. Timing seems to be working now, thanks all.

always initialize all your variables...

Well, if we consider this part of your code:
for (int i = 1; i < maxLength; i++;)
{
    // work...
    if(match()) solutionFound = clock(); // match() defined elsewhere in file
}

you're not always guaranteed that you'll find a match, so the variable solutionFound will contain garbage data that was not intended to be there (in case no match was found).
The main reason causing this issue is that the stack-frame of the function main or any function, in general, does not clean up beforehand.
Variables declared (but not initialized) inside a function belongs to a section called .bss reserved for uninitialized data. On the runtime of the executable these variables don't know what values should contain, so inherently they take the existing content on stack, which explains the fluctuating and sometimes negative values, as every time you run your program it will occupy a region of the memory that was occupied by another program that left it's content behind, and you're simply using that content (unwillingly). So remember to initialize your variables when you're not sure it they will be set somewhere.
I suggest you initialize it to zero and update the way you handle the case when you don't have a match.
